# How to compile an os install to an ISO

Tags: iso

I was wondering how I could compile a ubuntu install (22.10) into an installable iso with ubiquity to publish. Thanks!

Comment: The iso is already available here. https://releases.ubuntu.com/kinetic/

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *kinetic* and remains that until it reaches RC state, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 October 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-schedule/27263  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *kinetic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: I always suggest grabbing the *daily*, as you'll get the latest regardless of stage in the cycle; ie. *alpha*, *beta* or even RC.  The *beta* ISO URL provided earlier is outdated, where it's possible the current *daily* will be the final released ISO  (it's marked FINAL already on the tracker if you look, but if a respin is necessary that will replace it as final)  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: 22.10 will be released tomorrow, I am voting to keep open to stall. I am in Sri Lanka and a day ahead of most of the West.

Comment: 22.10 has now been released.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Has it?  Could just be CDN's are still updating, but I'm not seeing an announcement or update on Ubuntu.com.  Still, I voted to reopen - I may be jumping the gun as well, but I'm going to trust that the sun will rise tomorrow (and already has for you) and that 22.10 will be released imminently, so no sense in retracting my close vote now ;-).

Comment: @C.S.Cameron And the sun rose today, but now we're hearing that 22.10 *could be* [delayed a week](https://askubuntu.com/q/1436351/1165986).

Comment: Yeah, I've been checking the Ubuntu site all day in anticipation, Dang!

Comment: Thu Oct 20 19:13:20 UTC 2022: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436351/when-will-ubuntu-22-10-be-released