# When will Ubuntu 22.10 be released?

Tags: system-installation, downloads, 22.10

when i go to https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop i don't see the option to download Ubuntu 22.10

Am i trying the wrong link?

Comment: It hasn't been released... currently they're trying to assess a potential *blocker* bug that may cause the release date to shift a week. It's not expected for many hours yet even if the issues are cleaned. A quick *glimpse* of state can be seen at http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/440/builds where I'll suggest looking for the READY marks.

Comment: It has been released now https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-October/000285.html showing the official time of **Thu Oct 20 19:13:20 UTC 2022** ; ML post is late in the release list items of things to do (*for Ubuntu Release Team*).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It hasn't been released... currently Ubuntu Release Team are trying to assess a potential [*blocker* bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dkms/+bug/1991725) that may cause the release date to shift a week. It's not expected for many hours yet even if the issues are *cleared*.

A quick *glimpse* of state can be seen at http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/440/builds where I'll suggest looking for the READY marks. This link is both useful for ISO tracking & QA (*Quality Assurance*); where you're after the QA status.

Status can be viewed at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-22-10-release-status-tracking/30945 , though do note it's not updated that often, but tends to be a '*trailing indicator*' (*~economic usage*) rather than '*leading*'. The ISO QA site I provided first is more of a '*leading indicator*'.

If you needed '*real time*' views of what's going on though; IRC still provides the best clues.

Comment: FYI:  There will be a lot more the Ubuntu Release Team are monitoring/assessing than the bug report I used as example...   That *example* was bad enough the Release Team **warned** all *flavors* that it may cause a delay.. thus why I chose that issue. Either way we still have a number of hours before any release was expected (as I type this).

Comment: All of them are ready!! http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/440/builds

Answer (score 5):

It's actually "out" already.

Just might not been available on all Ubuntu mirrors when you checked.

You can download it from https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.10/

Comment: Updated with the correct link (yes it's out)

Comment: isn't that the beta version? shouldn't it be on this page https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: @JamesGates The webpage has not been updated yet. This is not the beta. The beta releases were named as `kinetic-desktop-amd64.iso`